# Ассоциативный массив в js

Tags: javascript, json

Есть ассоциативный массив вроде такого:

```
[
  {id: 12,  word: "hello"},
  {id: 15,  word: "world"},
  {id: 602, word: "foo"  },
  {id: 631, word: "bar"  },
  {id: 632, word: "baz"  },
  ...
]
```

Мне нужно получить доступ к одному из элементов. 
Элемент который мне необходим, содержит, скажем `id = 631`. Как **не перебирая** массив сразу получить доступ к этой строке? Или узнать под каким она номером?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте структуру массива в сам запрос. Это поможет другим участникам сообщества с похожими проблемами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Никак.

У вас не ассоциативный массив, а самый обыкновенный, и индексы в нём с id не связаны. Чтобы осуществлять нужную вам операцию без полного просмотра всех данных, нужно предварительно их перевести в другую структуру.

В вашем случае можно создать объект, ключами в котором будут служить эти самые `id`. Создайте пустой объект, и каждый элемент `e` запишите в него:

```
preprocessed[e.id] = e
```

Только имейте в виду, что объекты в JS могут иметь только строковые ключи.

#### Да нет же, всё не так плохо.

На самом деле, пересматривать все данные необязательно, если все `id` в массиве расположены по возрастанию, как в вашем примере. В этом случае вы можете воспользоваться любым алгоритмом поиска по отсортированным данным, из которых оптимальным по простоте/скорости является **двоичный поиск**:

- смотрите в середину массива
- если искомый `id` найден, результат готов
- если искомый `id` больше

  - рекурсия в дальнюю (правую, нижнюю) половину массива
- иначе

  - рекурсия в левую половину массива

В конце концов, поиск сведёт вас к массиву размером в один элемент. Либо это и есть искомый элемент, либо в массиве его не существует.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас изначально json строка, то необходимо сначала его распарсить:

```
JSON.parse(json_string)
```

А потом:

```
response.contacts[2].id // вернет 12683522
```

Answer (score 0):

В JS нет ассоциативных массивов, а есть объекты и если я правильно понял задачу...

```
var arr = { ..., id: 12683522, ... };

alert( arr.id );
```

Comment: "В JS нет ассоциативных массивов" - с некоторого времени эта информация неверна. ES6 Map. Но в данном случае, действительно замечательно подходит обычный объект.